# Node.js hubot execute commands on the server

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I am trying to execute a command on the server using hubot.
This example works for me:

```
  robot.respond /(cmd)/i, (msg) ->
    doing = spawn 'ls', ['-la']
    doing.stdout.on 'data', (data) ->
      msg.send data.toString()
```

However, I need to change the folder before I execute the command I want to execute.
What I want hubot to run is:

```
cd /var/folder && some-command
```

but changing the folder from the hubot script doesn't work.

The executed command has a lot of files loaded based on the folder it resides in so it seems I have to go to this folder.

How can I make hubot execute a command from a specific path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
process.chdir('/var/folder')
```

is what I was looking for.

Comment: if you use the child_process.exec(command[, options], callback) the options object takes a cwd  parameter which changes the "Current working directory of the child process"

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with hubot, but have you tried shell command chain something like 
**'cd /var/folder; some-command'**?