# How to execute shell script from hubot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, coffeescript, hubot

I got my first hubot up and running, and wrote my first few scripts based on the existing examples. My existing workflow, which I would like to integrate with hubot, is essentially based on several shell scripts, each one of them performing one task. The task can be relatively complex (git/svn checkout, compiling code with gcc, and running it). How can I execute a bash script with hubot? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625846/node-js-hubot-execute-commands-on-the-server), but it only addresses simple commands such as `ls`. I tried

```
build = spawn 'source', ['test.sh']
build.stdout.on 'data', (data) -> msg.send data.toString()
build.stderr.on 'data', (data) -> msg.send data.toString()
```

without any luck:

```
Hubot> execvp(): Permission denied
```

I checked the obvious things (`-rwxr-xr-x` permissions), and `export HUBOT_LOG_LEVEL="debug"`.
I am running hubot with the same user that owns the bash scripts.
Thanks.

Comment: Give complete path to `test.sh`?

Comment: I tried both without any luck: to give the complete path to `test.sh` and to call `process.chdir(scriptDir)` before calling `source`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference: the answer was

```
build = spawn '/bin/bash', ['test.sh']
```

Dah

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install hubot-script-shellcmd
```

is your doorway to the shell.